# What version of Checkstyle is getting used in warnings next generation plugin 6.1.1 from jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, checkstyle, static-code-analysis, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am trying to configure static code analysis on my jenkins server for maven project. I want to use google checks for Checkstyle based code analysis. To use appropriate google checks xml file I want to know the version of checkstyle used in warnings next generation plugin 6.1.1.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Warnings-ng plugin is not analyzing your code, it just creates visualization of checkstyle analysis results.

So you need to perform analysis by some other tool (e.g. maven) first and after than warnings-ng can show you results.